# add a grid to a MDI form

Tags: c#, winforms, mdi

I am new to windows form based application. So, What I started doing is, I added a mdi form and on clicking the sub menu items , for eg: I have a View main menu with customers, products submenu. When I click products, I get a grid filled with a dataset. But the problem is that, the grid is not showing any data. So, this is what i did:

```
private void products_clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

       cmd = new SqlCommand("getProducts", conn);
       cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
       da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
       ds = new DataSet();
       da.Fill(ds, "Productslist");

       dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;



}
```

I have already added gridview to the mdiform  and i'm thinking of updating it on every click. So, can u please let me know whether the way i'm doing is correct and also help me in doing the app?

Comment: where will you click to update??

Comment: i click the submenu item product when i need to fill the grid with products

Answer (score 0):

If you making a dashboard like stuff then it is ok. but if you are updating grid backend data then you must update it with every update and load it at mdi load. not at menu.

close all other form on your menu click rather  than updating grid.

Comment: k.. what do u say abt this: add a new form on clicking and have a grid on that

Comment: because it will be updated every time when update backend data that is related to the grid.. create a delegate to update the MDI form and make method definition on another form you are updating data or on the unload of the updating form.  try this.. it will make your app working well.. nobody like to click menu again and again..  If it seem little hard then create another page that show you data in grid.. depend upon your GUI considerations..